# Python: Calling a function that has a delay, without slowing down main loop

Tags: python, multithreading, function, pygame

I am attempting to create a simple game in python using the module pygame.  I have a main loop within the code for this game that is responsible for drawing shapes, moving the main shape using WASD, sprinting, colliding with other images, etc.

```
#Main Loop (DONT ADD DELAYS WITHIN MAIN LOOP)

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(50)

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and x > vel:

        x -= vel

    if keys[pygame.K_d] and x < 500 - width - vel:

        x += vel

    if y >= y6-60:

        y = 50

    if not(isJump):

        if keys[pygame.K_w] and y > vel:

            y -= vel

        if keys[pygame.K_s] and y < 500 - height - vel:

            y += vel

        if keys[pygame.K_TAB]:
            if worldMap == False:
                worldMap = True
                x4 = 120
                y4 = 100
            else:
                worldMap = False
                x4 = 600
                y4 = 600          

        if keys[pygame.K_LSHIFT]:

            if plyrStamina != 0:

                plyrStamina -= 10

                print(plyrStamina)

                width2 -= 10

                vel = 10

            else:
                vel = 5

        else:

            vel = 5

            if plyrStamina != 190:

                plyrStamina += 10

                print(plyrStamina)

                width2 += 10

        if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
            isJump = True

    else:     
         if jumpCount >= -10:
             neg = 1
             if jumpCount < 0:
                 neg = -1
             y -= (jumpCount ** 2) * 0.5 * neg 
             jumpCount -= 1

         else:
             isJump = False
             jumpCount = 10

     t1 = Thread(target=hungerSystem) #Calling hunger function 
     t1.start() 


     win.fill((0,0,0))

     #Draw images

     #Character
     pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,0,0), (x, y, width, height))
     #Stamina Bar
     pygame.draw.rect(win,(0,128,0), (x2, y2, width2, height2))
     #Hunger Bar
     pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,165,0), (x3, y3, width3, height3))
     #World Map
     pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,223,0), (x4, y4, width4, height4))
     #health bar
     pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,0,0), (x5, y5, width5, height5))
     #lava
     pygame.draw.rect(win,(255,160,122), (x6, y6, width6, height6))
     #update display
     pygame.display.update()

 pygame.quit()
```

I have a function that is responsible for the player's hunger.  This function will simply decrease a variable by -10 every 3 seconds using the module time.  This function is called within the main loop, and since the main loop doesn't have any delays, the function will constantly be called.

```
plyrHunger = 190
width3 = 190

def hungerSystem():

    global plyrHunger

    global width3

    if plyrHunger > 0:

        time.sleep(3)

        plyrHunger -= 10

        width3 -= 10

        print(plyrHunger)


    else:
        causeDeath = 1
        print("You're dead!")
```

An issue that I was having was caused by me attempting to call the function like this:

```
hungerSystem()
```

Which seems to slow down the entire main loop by 3 seconds since the function has to be finished for the main loop to repeat again.

To combat this I used the threading module which allows me to call the function hungerSystem without having to wait for the function to finish.

```
t1 = Thread(target=hungerSystem) #Calling hunger function 
     t1.start()
```

However, now I am experiencing an issue where the function seems to operate correctly once, and then afterwards the time.sleep within the hungerSystem function seems to be ignored as well as the if statement checking if plyrHunger is greater than 0.  The result is a very strange and unexpected continuous subtraction of the variable plyrHunger, without any delay at all.  Also, the variable will then be subtracted into the negatives even though there is an if statement put into place to prevent this exact thing happening.

In the function (below) the areas that I have commented seemed to be getting bypassed after the first call of that function.

```
plyrHunger = 190
width3 = 190

def hungerSystem():

    global plyrHunger

    global width3

    if plyrHunger > 0: #BYPASSED WHEN FUNCTION CALLED

        time.sleep(3) #BYPASSED WHEN FUNCTION CALLED

        plyrHunger -= 10

        width3 -= 10

        print(plyrHunger)


else:
    causeDeath = 1
    print("You're dead!")
```

Does anyone know a better way of calling this function rather than using Thread, since it seems to be causing issues?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably best if the code just keeps track of the time.  Record the time when a "hunger" point is deducted, then do not do it again until 3 seconds have elapsed.  Any use of `time.sleep()` will lockup your code.

I think using a thread to track this is not necessary:

```
import time

HUNGER_POINT_LASTS=3  #seconds

# About the player    
player_hunger_points = 10
player_hungry_time   = time.time()

while ( True ):
    now = time.time()

    # Is the player hungry now?
    if ( player_hungry_time + HUNGER_POINT_LASTS < now ):
        print( "Player is hungry ..." )
        player_hunger_points -= 1
        player_hungry_time = now

    # Has the player starved?
    if ( player_hunger_points == -1 ):
        print( "... starved to death" )
        break

    # ... rest of code

    pygame.display.update()
```

The code could also post an event into the normal pygame event queue:

```
USEREVENT_HUNGRY  = pygame.USEREVENT + 1
USEREVENT_STARVED = pygame.USEREVENT + 2

...

# Is the player hungry now?
if ( player_hungry_time + HUNGER_POINT_LASTS < now ):
    player_hunger_points -= 1
    player_hungry_time = now   
    if ( player_hunger_points > -1 ):
        new_event = pygame.event.Event(USEREVENT_HUNGRY)
    else:
        new_event = pygame.event.Event(USEREVENT_STARVED)
    pygame.event.post(new_event)


 ...

 if ( event.type == USEREVENT_HUNGRY ):
     # player just lost a hunger point, do something
 elif ( event.type == USEREVENT_STARVED ):
     # player starved, do something
```